# Range of a string program

Tags: c#

This is a program to get all the letters in a string in a specified range (in this case characters 3 through 7 of the word 'kangaroo').

Why am i getting an error at line `arr[i] = x[start+i];`?

I am not using Substring because my instructor wants us to figure out how to do it without it as an exercise.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MethodsPractice2
{
    class Program
    {
        static char[] GetRangeOfCharacters(string word, int start, int end)
        {
            string x = word;
            char[] arr = new char[end - start];

            for (int i = 0; i < end; i++)
            {
                arr[i] = x[start + i];
            }

            return arr;
        }

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            char[] endResult;
            string word = "kangaroo";
            int start = 3;
            int end = 7;
            endResult = GetRangeOfCharacters(word, start, end);
            Console.WriteLine(endResult);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Or, you could, of course, just use string.SubString.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're not using the `String.Substring` method?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: You might want to tell us what "blowing up" means, and you might want to show us line 20, so we don't have to count.

Comment: What's the expected result?

Answer (score 4):

I'll explain the error you are getting,

You have said that you wish to start at character 3, and fill `arr` which is has 4 entries, with the characters that start at `(3)` + `i`

`i` can be any number less than `7`.. 3 + 6 = 9; and `Kangaroo` has 8 letters in it... therefore you for loop at the minimum needs to go to

`i < (end - start)`

---

The other error could could get is i >= 4 in which case it would be trying to access `arr[4]` which is also out of range

---

```
0123456789
kangaroo
garo##  /// what arr would be - # = error
garoo#   // where i would get you - # = error
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you take too many characters in the loop:

```
static char[] GetRangeOfCharacters(string word, int start, int end)
{
    string x = word;
    char[] arr = new char[end - start];

    for (int i = 0; i < end; i++) // <--- here!!!
    {
        arr[i] = x[start + i];  
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Correct would be

```
for (int i = 0; i < end - start; i++)
```

I would use this instead (skipped invalid argument check):

```
static char[] GetRangeOfCharacters(string word, int start, int end)
{
    return word.Skip(start).Take(end - start).ToArray();
    // or more efficient: word.Substring(start, end - start).ToCharArray();
}
```

Comment: Why would you not use `string.SubString()`?

Comment: @Oliver: Because the method returns a `char[]` not a `string`.

Comment: Ok, `string.SubString().ToCharArray()`?

Comment: @Oliver: Probably more efficient. Edited my answer to add it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for the easiest way to print part of the string, the easiest way, as mentioned in the comments, is with the [`String.Substring` method.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx).  To get characters #3-7 of the word `kangaroo`, you could use:

```
String.Substring(2,5);
```

The 2 is the starting index (it's 0-based, so 2 is the third character), and 5 is the length.

If you need the array of characters (as your return type indicates), you could try using the [`String.ToCharArray` method,](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c7h58e5.aspx) which functions the same way:

```
x.ToCharArray(2,5)
```

Comment: I would imagine there is a reason substring isn't used (i.e homework)

Comment: @Sayse If that is the case, then see the other answers.  I didn't think about that.

Answer (score 1):

end is 7 so you are looping from 0 to 7 and so going at subscripts 3 to 10
so

```
for (int i = 0; i < end; i++)
```

should be

```
for (int i = 0; i < (end - start); i++)
```

or perhaps even clearer

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well end is 7, start is 3. 3 + 6 is 9. Kangaroo is only of length 8 so you're gonna get an index out of range exception (looping while i < end, and adding i to start to get the index). As others have suggested you should use substring instead of your current method.

```
  string subString; 
  if (end - start < 0)
      subString = null; // error!
  else
      subString = myWord.SubString(start, end - start);
```

Might also want to check that start and end are both less than `myWord.Length`

Comment: @Sayse yeah and he's doing `arr[i] = x[start + i];`. I guess I have an error in my arithmetic up above but that is still causing an index out of range exception, 9 or 10 doesn't make a difference, they're both out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

You're overflowing your array, arr[] by 1.  Quanity (end-start) gives you one less than the size of your range.

You need to use quantity (end-start+1) to size your target array.

Answer (score 0):

`arr` is an array with 4 slots (7 - 3).

But the code:

`for (int i = 0; i < end; i++)`

will loop 7 times (because `end` == 7), trying to write to a new position of `arr` on every iteration.

Q: How can you store 7 distinct values to an array with only 4 slots?

A: You can't!

(Your for-loop needs different constraints).